# CSS text-decoration- set none, but allow one or more attributes

Tags: html, css

If I have the following attribute:

```
html {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

But I wanted to allow one text-decoration, like 'line-through' to still be active...

Is it possible to do this?  How?

Edit:  I don't know what html this is applied to- it is dynamic through a browser plugin...

Thanks!

Comment: it would be possible if you will not set global styles

Comment: `#IdOfYourDomObjectThatNeedsToHaveTextDecoration { text-decoration: value; }`? I am not front-end developer, so not sure about it. Just an idea.

Comment: Check [csswizardry css guidelines](https://github.com/csswizardry/CSS-Guidelines) to avoid such problems

Answer (score 2):

You can specify this attribute on your particular element/elements, like

```
.decorated {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

This way, the `text-decoration` value of `none` will not get inherited.

**EDIT**:

http://jsfiddle.net/mGGnc/ demonstrates this. This will, of course, never work if the `decorated` class is added to the `HTML` element, since in this case there will be no property value inheritance. [CSS2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance) explains this.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov: http://jsfiddle.net/mGGnc/. Have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#inheritance

Comment: @Vladimir Starkov: It has nothing to do with `!important`. (It will matter if you add the `.decorated` class to `html` itself, though.)

Comment: @BoltClock: thanks. I just added a link to the related part of the CSS spec. I think I made it clear that the class should be added on _particular element/elements_, which should be styled.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Add it to answer itself. :)

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov I confused OP's usecase with [another situation](http://jsfiddle.net/matmuchrapna/mGGnc/2/). My apologies

Comment: @VladimirStarkov: right, that won't work, but using the value inherited from `html` looks like a good way to solve this.

Comment: Should have added in my OP (apologies)- I do not have control over what html this css is applied to- it is dynamic through browser plugin. So I cannot specify the particular elements to allow this on.  Idea is that this is a text-decoration reset css that removes all decorations- EXCEPT one or two that I would like to keep- like line-through.

Comment: Ack... No, there are no such selectors in CSS. I believe you might manipulate the computed and inline styles for all (or at least a subset of) target DOM elements, but that might get sluggish on huge documents, and you need to have access to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

If you will make separate a classes for your elements so than it will not get `inherited` from your `reset css`

You achieve your desired easily like this :-

```
html {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.anchor a {
text-decoration:line-through;
color:red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://tinkerbin.com/dMXXQnSA)

Answer (score 0):

The rule (not attribute) `html { text-decoration: none !important; }` has no impact, except in the rather hypothetical case where another style sheet sets the property on the root element, the `html` element. Contrary to popular misunderstanding, the [`text-decoration`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration) element is not inherited. When set to a value other than `none`, its effect partly resembles inheritance in a sense, though.

In a comment to an answer, you write: “this is a text-decoration reset css that removes all decorations- EXCEPT one or two that I would like to keep- like line-through”. As usual, general reset CSS stylesheets tend to cause problems rather than solve them. To override `text-decoration` settings on all elements, you would need to use the universal selector `*` (or a list of all known and unknown elements). But you cannot make it override settings that use some values and not override others, due to the way the property has been defined. Its value is either `none` or a space-separated list of keywords each specifying a “decoration”. So there is no way to just negate one of those keywords, without setting the property to a specific value.